# Live minification of CSS and JS on FTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, compression

Is it possible to work with CSS and JS via FTP on a website and after each save the compress file to be generated. in a way compass works on local servers but i don't need scss and less.

For example, i work in folder css/compress/style.css and the minified style should be generated in css/style.css, or, js/compress/script.js and the minified script should be saved in js/script.js

Comment: Voted to close as not a real question since I believe this to be overly broad.

Answer (score 2):

If you are editing over FTP, then you are downloading a copy of the file (even if this process is transparent to you).  I'd suggest trying to find a plugin to your text editor.  For example if you use Sublime Text: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build and [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/25186/sublime-text-auto-minification-build-system).

Otherwise you will need to run some command on the server (over SSH) or setup some cron-type job to try and minify the files every 5 min or something.  The build system approach might work the best.